# Cron job does not fire up after a timezone change

Tags: cron, timezone

I've tried eliminating many of the common errors,

1. ensuring that the PATHs are available for cron
2. there is an endline at the end of crontab file
3. the timezone is set-up by:

   ```
   cd /etc
   cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore /etc/localtime
   ```

Running `date` in bash, I get:

```
Tue Sep 17 15:14:30 SGT 2013
```

In order to check if cron is using the same time,

```
* * * * * date >> date.txt
```

is giving the same date output in date.txt.

This is the script I'm trying to execute:

`event.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo data > /root/data.txt
```

Using `crontab -e`, the line below works,

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/event.sh >/tmp/debug.log 2>&1

15 * * * * /bin/bash /root/event.sh >/tmp/debug.log 2>&1
```

However, when I tried some other arguments, hoping it would run at 2.50pm:

```
50 14 * * * /bin/bash /root/event.sh >/tmp/debug.log 2>&1
```

or

```
50 14 * * * (cd /root ; ./event.sh >/tmp/debug.log 2>&1)
```

it will no longer work. Seems like there is a problem with my hour argument. Nothing could be found in the `/tmp/debug.log` file either.

SOLUTION:

It turned out I have to restart the cron service after making changes to TZ.

Comment: any error in logs ? can you please try with absolute path instead of `~/event.sh` try with `/home/username/event.sh`

Comment: have you checked cron logs , once check in /var/log/messages or /var/log/cron or /var/log/syslog based on your distro

Comment: also do small modification like `* * * * * /bin/bash /root/event.sh >/tmp/debuge.log 2>&1`

Comment: You say that the time zone is set correctly, but are you *absolutely sure* of that? Try adding an entry like `* * * * * date` and confirm that `date` shows the expected time. Note that setting the TZ environment variable from within the crontab might not affect the time zone as used by the cron daemon itself, but it *will* affect processes launched through cron, so if you set TZ in your crontab I'd suggest commenting it out temporarily and setting the time using the system clock's timezone (probably UTC if you are single-booting Linux, but *may* be local time) instead.

Comment: The odds that you are seeing a bug in your cron daemon that causes the hour field to be considered incorrectly seems *exceedingly* small to me. More likely, you are misunderstanding what exactly it checks against. Did you remove any TZ assignment from the crontab file as I suggested?

Comment: Hi @Michael, i've edited my qns in response to your suggestions, it still fails to execute on time.

Comment: You are missing the point, @adsisco. I'm asking that you remove any TZ directive that might be in the crontab and then try it again. That will make date execute with the same TZ as the cron daemon itself does, letting us see what time zone cron wants the time fields in. /etc/localtime only affects display, not the system clock, and I *doubt* it affects cron. By doing this test, we can be *sure* that your problem is in no way related to time zones (which frankly it seems like to me).

Comment: actually, i think i just fixed it by rebooting the system... could it be that i have to restart cron service after making changes to TZ? @MichaelKjörling. THANKS! for pointing me to possible timezone problems.

Comment: @adsisco It's quite possible. In that case, simply restarting the cron daemon might have worked too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, the odds that you are hitting a bug that causes one field to be incorrectly considered seems *exceptionally* low. It's more likely to be a misunderstanding of what's going on and what cron expects.

In this case, we found out in the comments to the question that it was very likely a timezone related issue. For this, you would:

- Add an entry like `* * * * * date` to the crontab
- *Remove* (or comment out) any TZ assignment from the crontab

This forces `date` to run with the time zone setting of the invoker, *which means the cron daemon*. Look at the output; it will show what time zone cron is using internally, and thus highly likely which time zone it wants its time fields in. If you have a TZ assignment in the crontab, it is easily possible that the TZ environment variable assignment is passed through to the invoked commands *but cron itself uses some other time zone*. By commenting out or removing the TZ assignment, you avoid this ambiguity.

Also note that any changes to the system global timezone settings (including e.g. /etc/localtime) almost certainly require at least a restart of the cron daemon, and possibly (though unlikely) a system reboot to take full effect. Editing the TZ assignment in the crontab *should not* require a reload of the cron daemon, as it should detect that the file has been changed and reload it automatically.