# Adjust cron to new timezone without a system restart

Tags: ubuntu, cron, timezone

I've recently changed the timezone of my system.

```
timedatectl set-timezone [timezone]
```

I then restarted cron to adjust to the new timezone.

```
service cron reload
```

However, `cron` was still scheduling in the old timezone. I had to reboot the system before `cron` would adjust.

How can I force `cron` to use the new timezone if reloading the service won't work?

System: Ubuntu 16.04.

**EDIT**

This question is very similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90997/cron-job-does-not-fire-up-after-a-timezone-change), but the cause of the problem, as well as the solution, were different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron job does not fire up after a timezone change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90997/cron-job-does-not-fire-up-after-a-timezone-change)

Comment: The solution there was to restart cron. The solution here was to restart cron. Was it really that different? Or did it just feel different because the other answers didn't explicitly give the restart command?

Answer (score 1):

Executing a `reload` of `cron` didn't seem to be enough to refresh the timezone. However, running this command worked:

```
service cron restart
```

Thank you [Jeff Schaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) for your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439609/adjust-cron-to-new-timezone-without-a-system-restart#comment795065_439609).